# Change the size of playback button in Audio Player Widget of Flutter flow

Tags: flutter

Please let me know is it possible to change the size of playback button in Audio Player Widget of Flutter flow?
It is not reflected in Audio Player Properties.

Can we see the code of any widget in flutterflow? Either custom or inbuilt way to alter playback button of audio widget.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.